# How to wirte more than two if condition in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

In my case I have to check if user is registered or not,if yes he should redirect to home page else he can register and if status is 1 then he cannot register.

```
public function register()
{                                                       
    $userDetails = StartupAward::where('email', '=', Input::get('email'))->first();
    $status  = StartupAward::where('status','=',1)->first();
    if($userDetails->status == 1 )
    {
          return "you are already registered";
    }
    elseif($userDetails != null)
    {
          $getEmail = $request->get('email');
          $userDetails->name= $request->name;
          $userDetails->organization = $request->organization;
          $userDetails->save();
          $email = StartupAward::where('email','=',$getEmail)->first();
          $request->session()->put('id', $email);
          return redirect('iot-start-up-awards');
    }
    elseif($userDetails == null || $userDetails->status != 1)
    {
         $getEmail = $request->get('email');
         $input['name'] = $request->name;
         $input['email'] = $request->email;
         $input['organization'] = $request->organization;
         StartupAward::create($input);
         $email = StartupAward::where('email','=',$getEmail)->first();
         $request->session()->put('id', $email);
         Mail::send('email.toughtLeaderEmail',['useremail' => 
         Input::get('email')]  ,function($message) {
         $message->to('manjunath@designesthetics.com', Input::get('email'))
            ->subject('Startup Award Nomination Form');
    });
    return redirect('iot-start-up-awards');
}
```

Comment: You should have a IF-ELSE and inside ELSE your new IF-ELSE. ELSEIF is not needed.

Comment: I guess you want to apply simple boolean logic. Before you start, already registered user check should not be handled by controller, it should be handled in middleware.